# Unwanted mesh selection through other objects with x-ray off

Tags: selection-tools

I'm new so I don't know if this is a bug, or if I'm missing something.

Here I am trying to deselect some faces.

[image: A screen recording demonstrating the problem]

It doesn't select through the current object being worked on, only other objects.

Why should an object that is occluding my vision not also occlude the selection, considering I can just turn on x-ray to do that?

Restarting Blender didn't work.

Blender 3.1.2

Answer (score 0):

After messing around, I figured something out that works okay.
I just realized you can go into edit mode on multiple objects, and it saves your selection when switching between modes.

[image: A screen recording of what's described below]

When in edit mode, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> select the object that you want to block the selection.
Press <kbd>TAB</kbd> twice to go toggle to Object Mode and back to Edit Mode.
Make your selection.
<kbd>TAB</kbd> back to Object Mode then <kbd>LMB</kbd> select only your original object.
<kbd>TAB</kbd> back to Edit Mode.